# How does quantize work for Decimal object? InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]

Tags: python, decimal, quantize

So I'm having trouble understanding *quantize* for Decimal class. I've read the document and saw similar questions for my problem but for some reason, the solutions that were given did not work for me and I think I'm grossly misunderstanding what *quantize* even does. I thought it takes long digit float given as a Decimal and retains accuracy up to the precision I want but I'm not sure. I am trying to round up by 1 digit with precision and having worked with floats, I've noticed computation being off by a significant amount especially when dealing with a lot of digits. If anyone can help or explain what I'm missing, I'd greatly appreciate it.

This is just an example of one float I want to round.

```
from decimal import ROUND_HALF_UP, Decimal, getcontext

a = '9.688400490911022e+30'
# a is a numpy.float64

b = Decimal(a).quantize(Decimal('0.1'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)


>>>InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]
```